# Conference Room Book Solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, ootb

I need to create a Conference Room booking solutions in SharePoint Online environment, usage restricted to OOB only.

Any suggestion, where do I start from !

Answer (score 0):

A list for each room with "Calendar View" as the default view.

Then set up an overlay view to show all the rooms to make it easier to see which rooms are free

Answer (score -1):

the only solution for this case i have in mind would be the this one:
http://www.sharepointsapiens.com/calendar-events-invites/

Comment: I am afraid link only answers are not that helpful. Would you please include some brief explanation from the link you have specified. It would be helpful for future visitors.